# Arraylist of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create an ArrayList of Card objects.  This will represent the users hand. I have not really worked with arraylist before so any help would be appreciated. Below is my current attempt:

```
class Hand {

public static final int CARDS = 4;
ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();

public Hand(){

    for(int i=0; i < CARDS; i++){
    hand.add(new Card());
    }
}
```

Is this correct? and Specially if it is not correct, could somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine, does it run?

Comment: why not try this on a compiler.

Comment: Just add a `main()` function and run it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out is to compile the program and run it. :)

That being said, it looks fine. The only thing I would change is:

```
ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

to:

```
List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

If you are using Java 7, you can get rid of the second generic-parameter:

```
List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<>();
```

Typing with interfaces is a good habit to get into since it is easier for you to switch implementations later (like if you wanted to use `LinkedList<T>` instead).

Comment: As of Java 7 I believe the second generic declaration isn't necessary either. e.g. `Foo<Generic> var = new Foo();`

Comment: @Rogue Correct. But I am not sure what version of Java OP is using so I just left it like his question. :) But I have edited the answer to include the information.

Comment: @Rogue You still need a generic declaration, you can just use the so-called "diamond operator": `Foo<Generic> var = new Foo<>();`. If you just do `new Foo()`, that's a raw type just like in Java 5 or 6, and you'll get the same unchecked cast warning.

Answer (score 0):

Overall it seems correct, however you are just adding new `Card` objects without any sort of (known) randomization, so all the cards will be the same as far as I'm aware.

Comment: My card class handles the randomization, Thanks for your response

Comment: Best of luck on your program then :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems good,  just  a small suggestion:

```
ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

to:

```
List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<>(); //in java 7 the diamond symbol in right is allowed
```